# Howto enable/disable Flash in Preferences on Android WebView?

Tags: android, plugins, webview, settings, checkboxpreference

I'm developing a browser for Android.

Is it possible to create a `Checkbox Preference` to enable and disable Flash plugin (`webview.setPluginsEnabled`) in the `Preferences`?

```
<CheckBoxPreference
android:title="Enable/Disable Flash"
android:key="chkbox_flash"

Here I need the code to set WebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(boolean) 
to true or to false />
```

Comment: Never forget to specify your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't develop to Android, but seems you should add a listener to your CheckBoxPreference like this [checkboxpreference-onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045000/checkboxpreference-onclick) ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#onClick%28%29))

Then you set the state of the plugin off. Heres the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29). Basically, you have to do:

```java
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.OFF);
```

You shouldn't use `setPluginsEnabled`, as it is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginsEnabled%28boolean%29). Note, though, it'll disable any plugins, not only Flash.

Comment: And how would the listener look like? Sorry, I'm only a beginner.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496450/android-checkbox-preference and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su